# Не появляется кириллица при отправке сообщений на node-js

Tags: node.js, кодировка

При отправке сообщений через node js, используя следующий код:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const readline = require('readline-sync');
const utf8 = require('utf8');

const mail = readline.question("Enter your email login: ");
const pass = readline.question("Enter your email password: ");
const mail2 = readline.question("Enter the email address you want to send the message to: ");
const title = utf8.encode(readline.question("Enter a title: "));
const message = utf8.encode(readline.question("Enter the message: "));



// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
async function main(textMail){

  // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
  // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.mail.ru",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: mail, // generated ethereal user
      pass: pass // generated ethereal password
    }
  });

  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: mail, // sender address
    to: mail2, // list of receivers
    subject: title, // Subject line
    text: textMail, // plain text body
    // html: "<b>Hello world?</b>" // html body
  });

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);

}

main(message).catch(console.error);
```

Вводя следующие данные:

```
Enter your email login: ***@mail.ru
Enter your email password: ***
Enter the email address you want to send the message to: ***@gmail.com
Enter a title: Привет
Enter the message: Как дела????
```

получаю следующий ответ:

[image: Ответ, который пришел при помощи кода на node-js]

До того, как ввел в консоль "chcp 65001" приходило так:

[image: Ответ, который пришел при помощи кода на node-js, без ввода "chcp 65001"]

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: А зачем тут нужен модуль utf8?

Comment: @AlexeyTen , у меня было предположение, что проблема связана с тем, что при вводе данных есть несостыковка кодировки консоли и кодировки node, поэтому пытался таким образом исправить это, однако и с этим, и без этого оно не работает как я хочу)
Возможно это глупо звучит, понимаю, но я пока вообще многого не понимаю в node и поэтому и возникают такие сложности